# Plugin permissions xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin, plugins, xamarin.forms, permissions

I followed https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin on how to fix permissions for Andriod for camera and browsing pictures.

I still get error for `Cannot throw 'Plugin.Media.Abstractions.Mediapermission' on thread...`

I have been trying to fix this for a while and can somone be so kind and check [my code](https://github.com/Arminmosaffaie/CameraTest) ?

Newitempage.xaml.cs

```
using Plugin.Media;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace looool
{
    public partial class NewitemPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewitemPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Takephoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Test",
                    SaveToAlbum = true,
                    CompressionQuality = 75,
                    CustomPhotoSize = 50,
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
                    MaxWidthHeight = 2000,
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear,
                });

                if (file == null)
                    return;

                await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

                MainImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    var stream = file.GetStream();
                    file.Dispose();
                    return stream;
                });
            };

            Browsephoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
                    return;
                }
                var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
                {
                    PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,

                });


                if (file == null)
                    return;

                MainImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    var stream = file.GetStream();
                    file.Dispose();
                    return stream;
                });
            };

        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity (Andriod)

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.Media;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;

using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;

namespace looool.Droid
{

    [Activity(Label = "looool", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]

    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

MainApplication.cs

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;

namespace looool.Droid
{
    //You can specify additional application information in this attribute
    [Application]
    public class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
    {
        public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer)
          : base(handle, transer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
            //A great place to initialize Xamarin.Insights and Dependency Services!
        }

        public override void OnTerminate()
        {
            base.OnTerminate();
            UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        }

        public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity)
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity)
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity)
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks Beforehand!

Comment: You need to place the relevant code within your question, not an outside repo:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have tested your code on github. It works on both Android 7.1 and 8.1. What's your device or emulator API level? Have you tested it on other device?

Comment: The problem was that i used Liveplayer!